# How to change the value of an NSMutableArray at a particular index

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, lvalue

`[array objectAtIndex:i]` doesn't work as an L value, so it can't be used to set the object at index i.

Comment: And you looked at the docs how long before asking this?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use [`-insertObject:atIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABBHADI) or [`replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABBBECB).